# Make local Notification stay on lock screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uilocalnotification, lockscreen

I have a habit making app which reminds user of his habits via UILocalNotifications. However the time at which user should be reminded about his habit is not always the time he scheduled it.

My question is if there is a way to keep the notification on the lock screen after the user has unlocked his iPhone / iPad and not have it moved to the notification center, because it is rarely visited, kind of like it is on Android phones.

App is written in objective-c

You can check the app out here: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/life-habits-let-your-habits/id979064412?l=pl&ls=1&mt=8

Comment: This is not possible with local notifications; I'd suggest you create a [Today widget](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/NotificationCenter.html) instead.